# Convert special characters(UTF-8)

Tags: c++, string, utf-8, char

I am trying to convert charactes à with `#include <iconv.h>` but i receive garbage �.

This is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iconv.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    char *gbk_str = "àèì asdsa sd aä";
    char dest_str[100];
    char *out = dest_str;
    size_t inbytes = strlen(gbk_str);
    size_t outbytes = sizeof dest_str;
    iconv_t conv = iconv_open("ISO8859-1", "UTF-8");

    if (conv == (iconv_t)-1) {
        std::cout <<"iconv_open";
        return 1;
    }

    if (iconv(conv, &gbk_str, &inbytes, &out, &outbytes) == (size_t)-1) {
        std::cout << "iconv";
        return 1;
    }

    dest_str[sizeof dest_str - outbytes] = 0;
    puts(dest_str);
    return 0;
}
```

Come back with :
Itlian character: POLS 6000 Impianto riduzione d. velocità

byte encoding   :  50 4f 4c 53 20 36 30 30 30 20 49 6d 70 69 61 6e 74 6f 20 72 69 64 75 7a 69 6f 6e 65 20 64 2e 20 76 65 6c 6f 63 69 74 c3 a0

Converted: POLS 6000 Impianto riduzione d. velocità -> POLS 6000 Impianto riduzione d. velocit340

Comment: Quite possibly because your input string is not stored in UTF-8 in the first place. It's not a requirement of C++ for string literals to use UTF-8.

Comment: You should write the value of every char, before and after. This will help to find where there is a problem

Comment: Are you using visual studio? In that case `File > Advanced Save Options` and you can choose the correct Encoding, this solved my issues

Comment: You need to look at the actual bytes, to determine if what you have on the input side really is UTF-8 and to determine if what you have on the output side is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set your terminal character encoding to ISO8859-1. In my Linux's Mate Terminal it is:

Terminal >> Set Character Encoding >> Central European (WINDOWS-1250)

Then I was able to see correct output from your program. Without this change it was indeed a garbage.

Comment: Nope. In the `gbk_str` variable, `"àèìä"` are all defined in code page `1252` (_US & Western Eu_) while only `ä` is defined in code page `1250` (_Central Europe_).